# On two irreducible actions

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, general-linear-group

Is it possible to find an example of the following type?

Let $p$ be a prime and let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be elementary abelian finite $p$-groups (i.e., the additive group of two vector spaces over the field of characteristic $p$) of order $p^n$ and $p^m$, say.

Is it possible to embed $S=Sym(3)$ in $GL(n, p)$ and $GL(m, p)$ in such a way that in the corresponding action on $M=M_1\times M_2$ the only non-trivial $Alt(3)$-invariant subgroups are $M_1$ and $M_2$?

I asked about $Sym(3)$ because I thought it is the smallest possible order, but I would be happy even if it is possible to replace $S$ with any group of the form $H=\langle a\rangle\ltimes\langle b\rangle$, where $a$ and $b$ have prime power orders (and $H$ is not abelian)

I tried to find such an action with gap but it seems the prime $p$ and/or $n,m$ must be too large.

Do you know any example of this type?

Comment: I don't understand the remark about $n,m$ being large. If $3|p-1$ then there will be $A_3$ invariant subspaces of dimension $1$, and everything collapses; otherwise $3| p^2-1$ and there are invariant subspaces of dimension $2$ and so $m=n=2$ and so all will be clear. This leaves the case when $p=3$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I wrote "and/or" to take into account the fact that I will be satisfied if we can replace $Sym(3)$ by some metacyclic group of the form I said.

Comment: I'm still not sure what part $b$ plays. And the same sort of argument surely shows that if $a$ is of order $s^k$, $s$ prime, then it's not going to happen unless $p=s$, and then it's a question about $p$-groups?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I do not understand your remarks actually. You may have $Sym(3)$ as an irreducibly subgroup of $GL(2,5)$. On the same line you may have a cyclic group of order $3$ acting on a cyclic group of order $7$ naturally and this whole semidirect product can be seen as a subgroup of a $GL(n,p)$ for some $n$ and $p$. and the $7$-cyclic may be irreducible.

Comment: Suppose $a$ has order $h$ and $(h,p)=1$. Then by looking at the RCF we see that (as the action on $M$ is irreducible) that $a$ is represented by the companion of an irreducible polynomial, so that effectively $M$ can be taken as the additive group of a larger field $\mathbb{F}_{p^t}$ and $a$ acts as scalar multiplication by a primitive element of this field. The same will be true for each of $M_1, M_2$. Then I think there are other invariant subspaces of  $\mathbb{F}_{p^t}$-dimension $1$  in $M_1\oplus M_2$ - if I am wrong you've got an example.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In the example concerning $Sym(3)$ I asked that the subgroups were the only $Alt(3)$ invariant, which means that the analogous situation is $b$ which must act irreducibly on $M_1$ and $M_2$ not $a$. Now, I also added that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is not abelian; this maybe can further clarify.

Comment: I think you and I use different notations for the semi-direct product..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $p$ be any prime with $3 \not\vert p-1$, such as $p=2$, let $n=2$ and $m=1$, with $M_1$ a nontrivial irreducible $S$-module, and $M_2$ the trivial module. (Or, for odd $p$, you could take $M_2$ to be the module in which $(1,2,3)$ acts trivially but $(1,2)$ does not.) These are the only examples for $S_3$.

Comment: Can you explain why these are the only examples for $S_3$?

Comment: Moreover, do you think it is possible to choose $A_3$ acting irreducibly on both?

Comment: $S_3$ has only $3$ irreducible modules when $p \ne 3$ and only two in characteristic $3$. For $p>5$ that follows from looking at the character tables, and they are easily computed individually for small primes. So there aren't very many options! The $A_3$ does act irreducibly on both - it must do, otherwise there would be more two $A_3$-invariant subgroups (which is what happens when $3|p-1$).

Comment: @DerekHolt So the configuration can't arise if the "bottom" cycle of the semi-direct product acts non-trivially on both $M_1$ and $M_2$? Am I right??

Comment: Yes, because in that case the two actions would be equivalent, and so there would be diagonal invariant subgroups. But it could happen for other semidirect products of the type you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt. What happens in the case where the characteristic is the same as the bottom cycle? I couldn't get my aged head round that. Brian.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In that case the only irreducible action is the trivial action so there are no examples.